# sort object array descending depending on an integer of object (angular-typescirpt)

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I need helping sorting an array of user objects by their score. 
Each user has a userId, userName etc. and a score. 
I want to implement a leaderboard where the first user of the sorted array is on top and so on. 
Therefore I get my array of users like this (leaderboardcomponent.ts):

```
users: User[];

this._dataService.getUsers()
      .subscribe((Users: User[]) => this.users, err => console.log(err));

public getUsers = (): Observable<User[]> => {
    this.actionUrl = this.apiUrl + '/User';

    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl, { headers: this.headers })
      .map((response: Response) => <User[]>response.json());
  }
```

I tried:

```
this.users.sort(function (l, r) { return r.Score - l.Score; })
```

But I couldn't display the first user of the array in the corresponding html file. 
How do I sort the array and display the first user in html?

```
HTML that did not work: <mat-card>
                <mat-icon>filter_1</mat-icon>
                <span>
                  {{ users[0]?.Score }}
                </span>
              </mat-card>
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of this.users structure?

Comment: Take a look at [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: no  cause its in my Oninit method and I cant debug it and view the array

Comment: You're not setting `this.users` to the `Users` argument of the `subscribe`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what do you mean?

Comment: This line: `.subscribe((Users: User[]) => this.users, err => console.log(err));` does nothing. If you change it to `.subscribe((Users: User[]) => this.users = Users, err => console.log(err));`, then `this.users` will have data (once the subscription is fulfilled).

Comment: thank you @HereticMonkey that helped a lot!

Comment: Although it does sort most users now but it seems like my user wont be orten with it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try to change the sort method for like this:

```
this.users.sort((l:any , r:any) => { 
   l = l.Score;
   r = r.Score;
   return l < r ? -1 : 1;
})
```

```js
const users = [
  {Score: 19},
  {Score: 13},
  {Score: 22}
]

users.sort((l, r) => { 
   l = l.Score;
   r = r.Score;
   return l < r ? -1 : 1;
})

console.log(users)
```

And then just use this HTML:

```
<mat-card>
   <mat-icon>filter_1</mat-icon>
   <span>
     {{ users[0]?.Score }}
   </span>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: It is not woking, the l and r are not found:
(parameter) l: User
(TS) Type number is not assignable to User

Comment: Sorry, probably I forgot sets types for `l` and `r`, try it now

Comment: no error message now, but still no user displayed in the html :(

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `sort`.

```
let users = [
    {name: 'User1', score:10},
    {name: 'User2', score:100},
    {name: 'User3', score:98},
];

function compare( v1, v2 ) {
  if ( v1.score < v2.score ){
    return 1;
  }
  if ( v1.score > v2.score ){
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

users.sort( compare );
// [{"name":"User2","score":100},{"name":"User3","score":98},{"name":"User1","score":10}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this._dataService.getCurrentUserInformation().subscribe(
          user => this.user = user, 
          err => console.log(err));
        console.log(this.user);

        //get all users
        this._dataService.getUsers()
          .subscribe((Users: User[]) => this.users = Users, err => console.log(err));

        this.sortUsersDescending();

        this.getUserPosition();

      }

      sortUsersDescending() {
        function compare(v1, v2) {
          if (v1.Score < v2.Score) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (v1.Score > v2.Score) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        }

        this.users.sort(compare);
}
```

This works more or less, the current user, which is Sarah, is not sorted property (view image pls)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOoMW.png)

Comment: "0s"? Try to convert data for number. Why you get 0s in "score" type